# Restate the primal as dual problem (simple)

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality

Given the primal resource allocation:
$$
\min_{x} \text{ costs} = \sum_{i} c_i x_i
$$

$$
\sum_{i} x_i = D     \\ (p)
$$

$$
x_i \leq \text{CAP}_i \quad \forall i \text{ (}\lambda_i\text{)} \\
$$

$$
x_i \geq 0 \quad \forall i \\
$$

Now the solution of the dual is also given:

$$
\max_{(p, \lambda_i)} \text{Value} = pD - \sum_{i} (\lambda_i \cdot \text{CAP}_i) \quad 
$$

$$
c_i + \lambda_i \geq p \quad \forall i \text{ (Xi)} \quad
$$

$$
\lambda_i \geq 0 \quad \forall i \quad 
$$

$$
p \geq 0 \quad 
$$

Now what I did so far is the following: I wanted to see whether this solution is correct for the simple case in which we have $x_1$ and $x_2$ and thus restated:

$$\min \text{costs} = c_1 x_1 + c_2 x_2$$

$$x_1 + x_2 = D \\ (p)$$

$$x_1 \leq \text{CAP}_1 \quad (\lambda_1) $$
$$ x_2 \leq \text{CAP}_2 \quad (\lambda_2) $$

$$ x_1 \geq 0$$
$$ x_2 \geq 0$$

$$p (x_1 + x_2) + \lambda_1 x_1 + \lambda_2 x_2 \leq pD + \lambda_1 \text{CAP}_1 + \lambda_2 \text{CAP}_2$$

$$x_1 (p+\lambda_1) + x_2 (p+\lambda_2) \leq pD + \sum_{i} \lambda_i \cdot \text{CAP}_i$$

which yields:

$$ \max_{(p, \lambda_i)} \text{Value} = pD + \sum_{i} \lambda_i \cdot \text{CAP}_i $$
$$ p + \lambda_i \geq c_i \quad \forall i $$

$$ \lambda_i \geq 0 \quad \forall i $$
$$ p \geq 0 $$

Thus neither the objective function nor the constraints are correct. Can somebody tell me what went wrong in my approach? Thanks!

Comment: You will probably have better luck at https://or.stackexchange.com/.